# Function Returning NotesDocumentCollection is Empty

Tags: lotusscript

I have a function which returns a NotesDocumentCollection. When placed in debug I can see the collection contains 70 documents, when the process exits the function the collection is then empty. Does anyone know why the collection loses all the documents?

For example (a snapshot of the code)

```
Dim dc1 as NotesDocumentCollection
Set dc1 = returnDocColl(thisdb, key)

Function returnDocColl(db as notesdatabase, key as string) as NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim vw As NotesView
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection

    Set vw = db.getview("viewname")
    If Not vw Is Nothing Then
        Set dc = vw.Getalldocumentsbykey(key, True) 
    End If                                                                                      

    Set returnDocColl = dc
End Function
```

When in debugger I can see that dc contains 70 documents, when returnDocColl is set it also contains the 70 documents, but dc1 is set it contains no documents. The documents seem to be lost between the ending of the function and the setting of dc1.

I have also replaced the code calling the function with the actual code in the function and as expected dc1 contained 70 documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause for disappearing your document collection is that the related NotesView `vw` object is gone as it is defined within the function. The NotesDocumentCollection is based on the NotesView. When the NotesView is destroyed then the NotesDocumentCollection is destroyed too.

Set the NotesView `vw` outside your function and use it as parameter instead of NotesDatabase `db`.

Comment: Thanks Knut, that makes alot of sense actually.

But the code above was just a small snippet of the actual function. The function loops through 5 different databases trying to locate the documents. Because it looks in two different database types (the live and an archive) it has to check in two different views, depending on which one is in that database. Not the best but it is an old system that I've had to adapt! If I declared the db and vw in the Declarations section would that also fix this problem?

I can edit the question to include the actual function if that helps?

Thanks again Fee

Comment: Yes, it should fix the issue if you declare and set the dbs and views outside the function once before you call your function first time.